# Delphi Monitoring Existing Processes

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm new to this so sorry in case my question seems to be silly, I'm writing a Delphi program in which I'm running a list of external executables though multiple threads in a queue and waiting for them to finish using CreateProcess like:

```
 CreateProcess(Pchar(NotepadExe), Nil, Nil, Nil,
                 False, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                 Nil, Nil, StartupInfo,ProcessInfo),
```

and

```
WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

now the programs I called are performing lengthy jobs, so in case my program got closed while the external executables are still running, is there an easy way to regain access to the processes and waiting for them again? and what about the case when some of them are finished already?

Comment: Are those processes also developed by you or are they some third party programs? If they are developed by you you could implemnt code into them for each of them to go and register its own mutex whose existance you could then check.

Comment: While closing take note of the child processes' and your process' id. When run again, search for processes that have pids of the children with parent pid equal to your previous pid Open a synchronize handle and wait. Theoretically it is possible to come across same pids having the same relationship but different applications. Practically, ignorable.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099859/win32-how-to-enumerate-child-processes) for one way to enumerate running processes from Delphi.

Comment: If your program is calling `WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);` for every child process, how exactly is it closing "cleanly" before every child process has finished?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Job Objects: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx

Comment: @SilverWarior, No they were not developed by me.

Comment: @Yasir So using of mutexes is out of the question. Well this complicates things a bit. But then thinking about it. Why are you even closing your process monitoring program? Wouldn't it be easier to go and simply hide your program and leave the systray icon for restoring it when needed. This way you can still use the existing code for monitoring of process closures. You only need to add the code to hide your program UI when not needed. On newer versions of Delphi you can quickly achieve this by using of TTrayIcon component. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTrayIcon

Comment: Also what would happen if you would store all the information from ProcessInfo itno a file before closing of your prgoram and then loading that info back on restart. I have never tried this but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I did sort of what @SertacAkyuz suggested, and it works

During execution I add the current process id to a file using

```
GetCurrentProcessId
```

When I start my program I read from the file the saved processIds then determine which of the currently running processes are children which I already ran, afterwards I create a thread to open and monitor the same again

```
uses tlhelp32;
----
var Snap:THandle;
ProcessE:TProcessEntry32;
----
Snap:=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);
 ProcessE.dwSize:=SizeOf(ProcessE);

 if Process32First(Snap,ProcessE) then
 begin \\Iterate through running processes
      while Process32Next(Snap,ProcessE) do
       \\Determine whether it's a child process of the saved PiD
          if ProcessE.th32ParentProcessID = mySavedPiD then
\\ Creating the thread to monitor the process 
cnThread:=TContinueThread.Create(ProcessE.th32ProcessID);
cnThread.Start;
\\ In the thread Execute 
var hndl:THandle;   
----
    hndl:=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS ,False,PiD);
    WaitForSingleObject(hndl, INFINITE);
```

It might not be the best solution but it works for me for now, however, still I need to handle the delta (processes which got finished during my program absence)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread for each started process, wastes a thread. And the [internal thread resources are limited](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx). If you're using `WaitForSingleObject(,INFINITE)` now, take the time to learn about [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and start a single thread to wait on a number of processes. (Or learn about [jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) like @DavidHeffernan proposes)

Comment: A process is a system controlled container, managing system resources. Amongst those resources is at least one thread. I'm not quite sure how you would create a process without *"wasting"* a thread. If you can show me a single process that doesn't consume a thread resource, I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: If you have a process A that creates a thread to start a process B and then does `WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE)` on B's handle, then there's a stalled thread in process A sitting there. Looks like a waste to me, especially with multiples of B.

Comment: I have some other sequencing/parallelism functionalities which I couldn't achieve unless I used different threads.